# What is the recommended way to integrate with dynamics 365 from an onprem database?

Tags: cloud, dynamics-crm, integration

My client have decided to use Dynamics 365 (CRM) and now we are looking into how we should set up integrations. We separate initial migration from continuous integration and here we are talking continuous integration.

The scenario is that we have an existing application (not Dynamics) onprem that should send updates to D365. In best case we send an update instantly (or near instantly) and asynchronously to D365. Some days there might be nearly 60000 updates that need to be done but others reasonably less. We also know there is an upper limit per 24h in number of calls to D365.

Now, my question is, what are the recommended way to do integration from onprem application to D365 from a scenario like the above?

EDIT:
We have been looking into using OData api, batch api and Kingsway Soft. But for continuous integration... would Kingsway even be an option?! With OData we may update record for record either synchronously or asynchronously (with servicebus). With batch api we might update, like 100 per batch once per minute... with Kingsway... how often

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a similier solution using Azure service bus

You can fire data from JSON or simlier to the service bus from your on prem Dynamics then pick it off from into Dynamics 365, youll need to use either logic apps (non-code) or function app (code) to manage pushing messages onto the message queue from onprem and pulling them of into D365.

Id suggest to check out the service bus here...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview

Here is a brief overview of using logic apps to intergrate with the service bus..
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus

Comment: Yes, I like this pattern. This is my own first choice. Though, in this case we will still have 60000 calls some days and we are only allowed 100000 per day. Most probably we will reach the limit at some point...

Comment: Where is the 100k limit ? Not aware of a hard limit anywhere? But might be missing something...

Comment: It is second-hand information but what I heard is that it is an upcoming limit.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest two more ways fro data migration/data integration .

Below two are proven and stable product for data migration/integration. We have used them for numerous projects and works like charm for us.

1. [Scribe](https://www.preact.co.uk/microsoft-dynamics-365/scribe-data-integration)
2. [kingswaysoft](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-365)

Comment: Data migration, yes. Data integration...no,  would be my answer but maybe I am wrong. Of course it depends on how frequently we update. Once a day I believe it could work too.